# Setting Additional Properties in Spring JPA with Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to set some extra properties Spring MVC application Java - config style. In this case, I want to set `spring.jpa.show-sql = true`

In my `PersistenceJPAConfig.java` I have the following:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
//other annotated configurations
public class PersistenceJPAConfig{

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.banks.myapp" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties()); //fetches the properties
        return em;
}
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){ //All datasource properties are retrieved fine
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"));
      //set password, username, etc.
      return dataSource;
}

 Properties additionalProperties() {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql");//not fetching/setting property
      return properties;
   }
```

And my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mydatabase.com:5555/db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

All the tutorials I've found teach me how to configure extra props via xml. How can I grab this or any additional properties via the `Properties` method?

**EDIT**

Not a solution, but setting the property manually with `setProperties()` works and my SQL is shown

```
 properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql", "true");
```

Comment: why don't use environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql") then?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` bean defined? I'm pretty sure that's necessary for using the `@PropertySource`. If you do, try setting the `@PropertySource` value to `classpath:/application.properties` (note the leading /)

Comment: Thanks @Josh, according the the Spring docs I'd only need a `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` to setup a placeholder `${/myplaceholder}`, otherwise `@PropertySource` should be all I need. My properties are getting retrieved from the .properties file as my app connects to the database fine.